# Prevent ImageButton from going in background

Tags: android

Here's the Android ImageButton that I am trying to rotate.

[image: Button partially hidden on rotation]

It does rotate but as you can see from the screenshot, part of it goes to background/invisible during the rotation. How do I ensure that the ImageButton stays visible completely during the entire rotation?

Here's the Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageButton imgbt = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

        RotateAnimation ra =new RotateAnimation(0, 360);
        ra.setFillAfter(true);
        ra.setDuration(2000);
        imgbt.startAnimation(ra);
    }   
}
```

And the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mybutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is probably because you wrap imageButton in linearLayout and it sets imageButton's canvas size.

Comment: Try out my answer it will surely work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your LinearLayout, change this:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to this:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

So, you will ensure that the container is big enough to show the image button completely, even when it's vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `LinearLayout` **height** and **width** to `fill_parent` as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
imgbt.bringToFront();
```

Comment: The error must be on the parent then, like the others answer suggest, you don't have enough space in your LinearLayout, because of the weight

Answer (score 1):

Set **match_parent** to your ***LinearLayout*** height.

If you are not using weight then don't need to include it. So change

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

chnage your width and height parameter of the linear layout to fill_parent cause the use code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mybutton"
   />
```